# Determining what the compiler generates for a given C-style cast

Tags: c++, casting

My understanding of C-style casts is that the compiler runs through all sorts of increasingly complicated/dangerous permutations of C++-style casts until it finds one that works, then silently sticks it in. I'm in the process of working through a codebase and replacing these C-style casts with true, explicit C++ casts.

How can I determine which C++ casts the compiler generates for a given C-style cast?

If architecture and compiler are relevant, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 (though I'd prefer answers that are cognizant of Linux and GCC as well).

Comment: (I try to have a 'What I've tried' section for each question I ask, but in this case, I really have no idea where to start.)

Comment: I think there is really no other way than just looking at the codebase and deducing by yourself which cast would be appropriate. You can look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) at the order in which explicit casts are tried by the compiler

Comment: I think your question would likely gather considerably more attention if you added a few trivial, and not-so-trivial, examples of what you're concerned about.

Comment: @Whoz: In this case, I think examples would only demonstrate motive, not clarify what I'm asking for. I'm mostly curious for theoretical reasons. Let's assume my motive is iron-clad =)

Comment: If that is the case, then the answer to your theoretical question is to (a) trace your codebase in relation to the rules of the standard, and (b) the only iron-clad answer to "what the compiler generates.." questions: look at the intermediate assembler.

Comment: I was hoping for something less brutal/weedsy, but if that truly is the only way, I'll accept it as an answer (after a day, just in case someone knows of a better way)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are modifying the code anyway, you might first see if there is a way to refactor the code to not require the cast. If that proves fruitless:

- Most of the time, you should use `static_cast`. The most common use of this is turning a `void *` into a `T *`.
- If you are trying to drop a `const` from an object, you need `const_cast`.
- If the cast is truly between incompatible types (like, turning an `int` into a pointer), you will need `reinterpret_cast`.

As described C++11 §5.4/4, when the compiler encounters the cast notation, it should be attempting the conversion by following the recipe below until the first one that generates a valid result:

> The conversions performed by
>   — a `const_cast` (5.2.11),
>   — a `static_cast` (5.2.9),
>   — a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
>   — a `reinterpret_cast` (5.2.10), or
>   — a `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
>   can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion.
>   ...<sub>***`static_cast` has some tweaks, see below***</sub>...
>   If a conversion can be interpreted in more than one of the ways listed above, the interpretation that appears first in the list is used, even if a cast resulting from that interpretation is ill-formed. If a conversion can be interpreted in more than one way as a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`, the conversion is ill-formed.

The standard says that the `static_cast` that is performed on behalf of the cast notation is slightly tweaked to work even if there is non-`public` inheritance.

> The same semantic restrictions and behaviors apply, with the exception that in performing a `static_cast` in the following situations the conversion is valid even if the base class is inaccessible:
>   — a pointer to an object of derived class type or an lvalue or rvalue of derived class type may be explicitly converted to a pointer or reference to an unambiguous base class type, respectively;
>   — a pointer to member of derived class type may be explicitly converted to a pointer to member of an
>   unambiguous non-virtual base class type;
>   — a pointer to an object of an unambiguous non-virtual base class type, a glvalue of an unambiguous
>   non-virtual base class type, or a pointer to member of an unambiguous non-virtual base class type
>   may be explicitly converted to a pointer, a reference, or a pointer to member of a derived class type, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think you misunderstood my question. I have a pretty good understanding of the C++ casts and when they should be used. What I'm wondering about is how to find out what a C-style cast gets converted to by the C++ compiler; ie, "what already is?", not, "what should I do?"

Comment: This is described in detail in section 5.4 of the C++ 11 standard. Do you want the quote?

Comment: The standard describes the casts 'tried' by the compiler, and their order. It doesn't describe exactly which [set of ]cast[s] is generated on line X of file Y in codebase Z. How do I find that out? The obvious answer is "look at the assembly", but I'm hoping for something cleaner and more friendly than that. =p

Comment: It looks like since `static_cast` is actually tweaked for the cast notation, there may be cases where you cannot remove it.